# add users to central admin but don't allow them acces to change security or permissions?

Tags: permissions, security, central-administration

Is it possible to give users access to Central Admin but deny them access to change security or permissions.

For example, they can do everything from creating a web application, service application, to doing backups but be unable to do basic things such as giving users access to Central Admin or even deleting them.

Many thanks,
Sepaka

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more as to why you need this?  End users creating web apps and service apps in SharePoint is the stuff of admin nightmares

Comment: Yes, you right Dave. This is for Admins - ofcourse we can't give users access to central admin. We basically looking for a way where we can actually use one account for basic SharePoint Admin tasks. We don't want Admins giving their accounts to CA for security reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this can be done at least not without some really heavy customization. Maybe you can mimic the entire CA with [custom application pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798467.aspx) but then you are reinventing the SP.

In SP2010 you have 2 permission groups for CA: Farm Administrators and Delegated Administrators. If you like to explore more read: [SharePoint 2010 Delegated Administration](http://blogs.architectingconnectedsystems.com/blogs/cjg/archive/2010/12/06/SharePoint-2010-Delegated-Administration.aspx) but this doesn't solve your issue.

Comment: DO you think creating new permission level would help resolve the issue?

Comment: As far as I know CA doesn't work like regular front end site. It uses groups to determine permissions (Farm and Delegated Administrators in 2010)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It looks like I have a long way to go. Thanks again.